# Do not scroll parent scroll when we are on any child scroll . React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have one dropdown in which i am showing track list.
When user scrolls dropdown and reaches end of the list parent window scroll is getting scrolled.
I want to stop parent scroll using react or pure javascript.
can we do it using **onWheel** event of react ?

I Tried below easier way but this is not accepted cause they don't want to hide scrollbar.

```
disableScroll() {
     this.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
}

enableScroll() {
    this.body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
}

 render(){
    return (
        <div onMouseOver = {this.disableScroll.bind(this)} onMouseOut = {this.enableScroll.bind(this)}></div>
    )
  }
```

This solution is not acceptable  and i dont want to use jquery here.

Comment: Have you tried cancelling event bubble?

Comment: @Bardo I tried it  , its not working  , i need to calculate it using deltax and y

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code

```
onChildScroll(e) {
    var isScrollingDown = e.nativeEvent.wheelDelta || -e.nativeEvent.detail;
    e.currentTarget.scrollTop += (isScrollingDown < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

Now its working fine